# Error creating Private Endpoint for OpenAI - ai-service doesn't have CustomSubDomainName

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure, azure-openai

Unable to create Private Endpoint for OpenAI Service. I am not specifying optional argument `custom_subdomain_name` since per [doc](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/cognitive_account) the property `custom_subdomain_name` is optional.

#### Terraform config:

```
resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "private_endpoint" {
    for_each = {for private_endpoint in local.private_endpoint_list : "${private_endpoint.name}" => private_endpoint}
  name                = ...     
  location            = ..
  resource_group_name = ..
  subnet_id           = ..

  private_dns_zone_group {
    name                 = ...        
    private_dns_zone_ids = ["/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/yyy/providers/Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones/privatelink.openai.azure.com"]
  }

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = ...    
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_cognitive_account.openai_services[each.value.name].id
    is_manual_connection           = false
    subresource_names              = [each.value.subresource_name]
  }
}
```

#### Error message:

```
Error: creating Private Endpoint (Subscription: "xxx"
Resource Group Name: "yyy"
Private Endpoint Name: "xxx-oai-service-account"): performing CreateOrUpdate: unexpected status 400 with error: AccountCustomSubDomainNameNotSet: Call to Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts failed. Error message: Account /subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/yyy/providers/Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts/xxx-oai-service doesn't have CustomSubDomainName

  with module.openai_service.azurerm_private_endpoint.private_endpoint["xxx-oai-service-pe-account"],
  on ../modules/LandingZone/AIKM/openai_service/main.tf line 84, in resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "private_endpoint":
  84: resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "private_endpoint" {

##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
##[section]Finishing: Terraform Apply
```

Comment: If you've created an `OpenAI Cognitive Services` account with a custom subdomain, you'll also need to provide a custom domain in the endpoint configuration. You can check whether you created the `OpenAI` account with a `custom domain` using the following command: `az cognitiveservices account show --name <account-name> --resource-group <resource-group-name>` Here is my [result](https://i.imgur.com/eI3YQMl.png)

Comment: I have not specified this argument in `azurerm_cognitive_account`. Also, here is the endpoint result from command `"endpoint": "https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/"`.

Comment: Kindly share **az cognitiveservices account show** command results here.

Comment: Here is the [pastebin](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/pyXGfCYfsb/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Endpoint Name: "xxx-oai-service-account"): performing CreateOrUpdate: unexpected status 400 with error: AccountCustomSubDomainNameNotSet: Call to Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts failed. Error message: Account /subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/yyy/providers/Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts/xxx-oai-service doesn't have CustomSubDomainName
```

> The `CustomSubDomainName` is optional for the `cognitive_account` as per the Terraform [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/cognitive_account), but it is not optional for the private endpoint

Even if you haven't created a **cognitive_account** without a custom domain name using Terraform, it is still mandatory for network operations.

I created `cognitive_account` without custom domain name.

[image]

In the portal, it is prompting me to generate a `custom domain name` for any `network` operations, as shown below.

[image]

However, when you create a **cognitive_account** from the Azure portal, it is created with a custom domain name by default, which is not the case when using Terraform.

To create a `Private Endpoint` for `OpenAI`, please generate a `custom domain` in the portal if it hasn't been created through `Terraform`.

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name = "existing-RG"
}
data "azurerm_cognitive_account" "openai" {
  name                = "venkat-openai-account"
  resource_group_name = "existing-RG"
}
data "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "subnet-1"
  virtual_network_name = "venkat-open-ai"
  resource_group_name  = "existing-RG"
}
resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "example" {
  name                = "privatelink2.openai.azure.com"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}
resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "example-pe01" {
  name                = "venkat-openai"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  subnet_id           = data.azurerm_subnet.example.id


  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "venkat-openai"
    private_connection_resource_id = data.azurerm_cognitive_account.openai.id
    subresource_names              = ["account"]
    is_manual_connection           = false
  }

      private_dns_zone_group {
    name                 = "default"
    private_dns_zone_ids = [azurerm_private_dns_zone.example.id]
  }
  depends_on = [ azurerm_private_dns_zone.example ]
}
```

**Terraform apply**

[image]

Comment: Ok, let me try this. In my case the Private DNS Zone exist already `privatelink.openai.azure.com`. Unsure why needs another `privatelink2.openai.azure.com`.

Comment: If you have Private DNS Zone already, you can use the same by using data block.